# firestore read permission denied, but it works in simulator with set IDs

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am trying to filter out posts that were hidden by the user. streaming is simple:

```
 StreamBuilderWrapper(
      shrinkWrap: true,
      stream: postRef
          .orderBy('stars', descending: true)
          .orderBy('timestamp', descending: true)
          .snapshots(),
      physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
      itemBuilder: (_, DocumentSnapshot snapshot) {
        Review reviews= Review.fromJson(snapshot.data());
        return posts.postId != null
            ? Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 12.0),
          child: Reviews(review: reviews),
        )
            : Container(
          child: Center(
            child: Text('balhblahblahb'),
          ),
        );
      },
    ),
```

trying to use firestore rules to set the read permission, where hidingUserId is an array of users, and isHiddenBy a currentUser id:

```
match /reviews/{review}{
  allow read: if request.auth != null && !(request.auth.uid in 
                 request.resource.data.hidingUserId) 
              || request.resource.data.isHiddenBy == null || 
                 request.resource.data.isHiddenBy != request.auth.uid
  allow delete, update, create: if request.auth != null
}
```

playing with rules in simulator with IDs works fine. they deny the read when the userId in one of the conditions, and allow read if userId is not in. However, when I test the app on the android device, I get the:

```
[Firestore]: Listen for Query(target=Query(reviews order by stars, - 
timestamp, -__name__);limitType=LIMIT_TO_FIRST) failed: 
Status{code=PERMISSION_DENIED, description=Missing or insufficient 
permissions., cause=null}
```

why is the denial of permission? how to structure the rules, so it filters out the posts if the user has hidden it? thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Firebase's security [rules are not filters](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#rules_are_not_filters); they don't inspect each individual document to see if it matches the rules. Instead they check the query/read operation you run against the rules to ensure it only requests documents that match those rules.

So you will have to replicate the condition from your rules in the query, an approach known as [securely querying data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-query). If you replicate the filter on `hidingUserId` in your query, the query meets that clause of the rules and that part of the rule will pass.

Unfortunately it is not possible to do an OR condition across multiple fields in Firestore, so it is not possible to replicate the entire rule in a query. If you can translate the conditions into a set of AND conditions, it should be possible to translate it into a query though - so that would be the direction I'd look.

Comment: aan, i got the logic now. Thank you! But now am back to the query where I need to use .where() and .orderBy(). And this is an issue! it is either expensive, or just crushes, or I am forced to order by some stupid value like userId... how come there is no a solution to 'whereNotIn' or 'arrayDoesNotContain', and not be forced to orderBy() by the field that invoked inequality?

Comment: Firestore queries are based on having an index, and being able to look up the values with a single operation. That's the only way it can meet its performance guarantees. Since the indexes don't contain information about documents without a certain value, such queries are not possible at the moment. It never hurts to [file a feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/) of course.

Comment: thanks! now, I have a different question, but related to this. will ask it in a new question.